# How to store nested loop data

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to store data like df[month,pr]. How to do that? What I have done is in below.
I want to do it

```
month=[j,f,m]
pr=[32,50,75,110,150,210,260]
df = dict()
for k in month:
 for i in pr:
  df[k,i] = expence.loc[expence['price']==i]
```

If I use only i or j like below then it executes successfully

```
pr=[32,50,75,110,150,210,260]
df = dict()
for i in pr:
 df[i] = expence.loc[expence['price']==i]
```

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: `df[j,i]` is single values  that's why you are getting error

Comment: How to resolve that? any idea will be appreciated.@deadshot

Comment: can you post  the sample dataframe and expected output

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you are writing df[j,i], what your program is understanding is that you are providing j as the key and i as its value this is why it is giving an error. You can solve the problem by making it a nested dictionary. Maybe a slight change in the code might fix your issue.

```
month=[j,f,m]
pr=[32,50,75,110,150,210,260]
for j in month:
    df[j] = dict()
    for i in pr:
        df[j][i] = expence.loc[expence['price']==i]
```